# What is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Hi I'm beginner to java program, 
I'm getting one exception error in common sort array program

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] arr1={4,5,6,8};
    int[] arr2={5,4,2,1};
    int[] arr3={4,5,3,2};

    for(int i=0;i<=arr1.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=arr2.length;j++){
           for(int k=0;k<=arr2.length;k++){

             if(arr1[i]==arr2[j] && arr2[j]==arr3[k])
             {
                System.out.println(arr3[k]);
             }

          }
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove all `<=` and write only `<`. Arrays are indexed from 0 to length -1 only.

Comment: Thanks, @DeepanshSachdeva can you please explain me the full code.

Comment: That should be your job to understand. Also, I would like to tell that this code doesn't seem to sort anything, it just prints common values from all array.

Answer (score 0):

Java has array indexed from `0` to `length - 1`. So instead of less than equal to operator `<=` you should use less than operator `<` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in for loop condition, you have only 4 elements in array and array index start with zero so your loop must start from 0 to 3 but <= operator checks for the forth index in array which not exist so just use < so the loop terminates after evaluating last index